# TextChanged event only fires when I put my cursor in the textbox and change the text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TextChanged Even on a textbox and when I enter data into it, it updates another textbox which in turn is supposed to fire a TextChanged Event, but it is not firing until I put my cursor in the TextBox.  Is there a solution to this?

Code for updating the Extended Price when Qty Changes:

```
protected void txtQty1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtQty1.Text != string.Empty && txtUnitPrice1.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            int qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty1.Text);
            double unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(txtUnitPrice1.Text);

            double extendTotal1 = qty * unitPrice;

            txtExtPrice1.Text = extendTotal1.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Code for updating the extending price When Unit Price changes:

```
    protected void txtUnitPrice1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtQty1.Text != string.Empty && txtUnitPrice1.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            int qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty1.Text);
            double unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(txtUnitPrice1.Text);

            double extendTotal1 = qty * unitPrice;

            txtExtPrice1.Text = extendTotal1.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Finally, this should update the Grand Total When Extending Price Changes:

```
 protected void txtExtPrice1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtExtPrice1.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            double extendedTotal1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtExtPrice1.Text);
            double grandTotal = Convert.ToDouble(txtGrandTotal.Text);

            grandTotal += extendedTotal1;

            txtGrandTotal.Text = grandTotal.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Is it true that I should probably make Grand Total a Static Variable?

Comment: I guess that should be the desired behavior. Imagine, the event firing when you try to set the text programatically in the code.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to happen.  I am building an invoice app, so when I enter a quantity and a price in their respective fields, the extended price should update which should fire its text changed event and update the grand total

Comment: According to MS, "This event is raised if the Text property is changed by either a programmatic modification or user interaction". Maybe posting some code would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the code to update the grand total from the first textchanged event and not worry about it not working when you try and cascade into another one.

Comment: I was going to do that, but then I deferred from it, but I forgot why, lol.

Comment: I have tried the other solutions, but due to time constraints, I have used yours.

Answer (score 1):

No clue if this will help or not, since the code (mostly) worked for me, but I was getting odd totals in the Grand Total, so I changed the event handlers to "Validating" for Quantity and UnitPrice (and hooked them both to the same event handler, since they're doing exactly the same thing...) (EDIT:Yes, I faked some of the logic, including arbitrailly setting the GrandTotal if it was empty).

```
        private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            int qty = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            double price = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            double totalPrice = qty * price;

            textBox3.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double bTotal = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text)) textBox4.Text = "100.00";
        double gTotal = double.Parse(textBox4.Text);

        gTotal += bTotal;

        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox4.Text = gTotal.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The textchanged event is not getting fired in the second textbox as it does not have the focus.

Add this line before , when you want to textchanged to fire.

txtBox2.Focus();

// do what you needto do witht the second text box.

txtBox1.Focus() ;

This should work

Sujay

Comment: I had a similar problem (where I was programmatically setting the Text property on a WPF TextBox control, and the TwoWay binding was not being updated), and this seems to have fixed it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a silly question, but are all of these events hooked up to the corresponding controls?

If so, a breakpoint on the first row of each event should help you track down the problem super quick.

If not, there's your problem :).

**UPDATE:**
I believe I found your problem. If you are *programatically* setting a textbox value to the same value it already contains, the TextChanged event will **NOT** fire.

So, in your case, if you are changing the value in the txtQty1 or txtUnitPrice1 textboxes to the same value they already contain, then the value in the txtExtPrice1 textbox is *programatically* being updated to the same value it already contains; hence, your txtGrandTotal.Text property is not updating because the event that updates it (**txtExtPrice1_TextChanged**) is **not** being fired.

Comment: Regarding your update, I have used different values.  The only time the Total TextBox event is fired is when I put my cursor in there, enter a number and tab out.

Comment: Ah... I see. Then I would go with the breakpoint suggestion; you'll have it nailed down in a matter of minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem here is that you are trying to use GUI controls to perform business logic. This is always a bad idea. GUI controls are designed to do one thing and one thing only: interact with the user. Trying to do anything else with them, such as perform calculations, will only lead to problems down the road.

Try reading up on the MVP (or MVVM) pattern. It will show you how you store the logical data for a view in a model, which is also where you do all your calculations. The GUI controls are merely updated when the corresponding data in the model changes. For example, a partial implementation of your model might look like this:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged {

#region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if(null != handler)
         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

      switch(propertyName){
         case Quantity:
         case UnitPrice:
            OnPropertyChanged("ExtendedPrice");
            break;
         case ExtendedPrice:
            OnPropertyChanged("Tax");
            OnPropertyChanged("GrandTotal");
            break;
         case Tax:
            OnPropertyChanged("GrandTotal");
            break;
      }
   }
#endregion

   private int _quantity;
   public int Quantity{
      get { return _quantity; }
      set {
         if (value != _quantity) {
            _quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
         }
      }
   }

   private decimal _unitPrice;
   public decimal UnitPrice {
      get { return _unitPrice; }
      set {
         if (value != _unitPrice) {
            _unitPrice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UnitPrice");
         }
      }
   }

   public decimal ExtendedPrice {
      get { return Quantity * UnitPrice; }
   }

   public decimal Tax {
      get { return ExtendedPrice * TaxRate; }
   }

   public decimal GrandTotal {
      get { return ExtendedPrice + Tax; }
   }
}
```

Now, the controls in your view can be bound to the properties of your model, and you can be sure that no matter how the Quantity or UnitPrice is changed (whether by the user through the controls, or by your own code), the derived amounts will be changed accordingly.